# Symbian - find if device is connected to internet

Tags: java-me, symbian

Is it possible using the Symbian Java library to find whether the device is connected to the internet or not?

I don't want to wait for an exception to find out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no practical way to do this in either standard J2ME or using any Series60 Java extension I have heard of.

Trying to contact a remote server and measuring the time it takes to do so would not be a reliable test because of irregular network coverage (and it would force the device to connect to the internet if it wasn't already).

Comment: Thanks. Right now i'm just listening for exceptions to check whether the phone has internet connection or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about the network starting with S60 3rd Edition FP 2 phones through a series of system parameters. *com.nokia.network.access* or *com.nokia.mid.networkavailability* may server your purpose. There are a few other properties that may be useful for network access, see the complete documentation on system properties http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-1F6DF24F-40E4-4450-80F6-783C996A25D7.html